# WPF Binding in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Similar questions galore for this and I just cant seem to figure out what is going on.

I'm short bus struggling to get my ListView populated, being bound to an ObservableCollection...

Code:

```
<controls:MetroWindow
       ...blah...
        Title="MainWindow" x:Name="Main" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Main}"   

<ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="FileNames" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="221" Margin="10,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258" 
             SelectionChanged="FileNames_SelectionChanged" BorderThickness="2"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Reports, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label CacheMode="{Binding Path=FileName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    

    </ListBox>


//Code Behind

public ObservableCollection<ReportsModel> Reports { get; set; }


Reports = setReports();
```

ReportsModel impls INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public sealed class ReportsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

I can step in and see that Reports gets populated fine and that the filename field is also populated on each report but nothing is showing up in my ListBox.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference holding the `ObservableCollection<ReportsModel>` named `Reports` can't have a plain getter/setter. You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChange` on the `Main` class and change Reports to signal a property change like this

```
private ObservableCollection<ReportsModel> _reports;

public ObservableCollection<ReportsModel> Reports 
{ 
   get { return _reports; }
   set
     {
         _reports = value;
         PropertyChanged("Reports");
     } 
}
```

---

> ReportsModel impls INotifyPropertyChanged

The data held has nothing to do with the collection's property `Reports` binding change notification.

Answer (score 1):

You should enhance your code with everything around `PropertyChanged`. That means:

Main should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
Notify the UI when the Source changes, for example

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Reports"));
}
```

**Edit after slightly changed question:**
the Reports valiue should be get/st in the following way to avoid problems:

```
private ObservableCollection<ReportsModel> _Reports;
public ObservableCollection<ReportsModel> Reports
{
    get { return _Reports; }
    set
    { 
        _Reports = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Reports"));
        }
    }
}
```

I guess `Main` has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` too.

Comment: thanks RepotsModel does impl INotifyPropertyChanged, and I updated the bindings to have the UpdaetSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged", still no dice. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` only makes sense on two-way or one-way-to-source bindings, which OP doesn't have.

Comment: it also makes sense in a one-way-binding. how else should the UI get to know the Source changed?

Comment: You have misunderstood what it means. Get back to the documentation.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 I edited the answer after you edited your question, please take a look at it

Comment: @Clemens okay, I guess you should never trust a colleague... I'll look at the dokumentation myself. I never thought I might have been taught something wrong because it worked every time.